# Accidently deleted sanity studio from pc, How can I get my schema back?

Tags: content-management-system, sanity

My noob ass removed Sanity Studio from my pc ( didn't initialize it as git repo). Now is there any way to get the studio back to the pc for local development from the deployed studio? I deployed the studio but don't have a local copy. I just need the schema back

Answer (score 1):

Sanity don't store the raw schema source files in their end, but as long as you can access the deployed studio there is a way to recover at least parts of it from the minified javascript bundle. Instructions here: https://gist.github.com/bjoerge/b4369aa6ae0ed5c64029b9cdd41198dc

Comment: Wow, sir thank you so much. Just one question.... when I redeploy my studio again will it delete my content already present in deployed sanity studio?

Comment: Happy to help! No, redeploying your Studio doesn't affect your content :)